# What is the function of the 'assert' keyword in the J programming language?

Tags: assert, j

What is the function of combining `assert` and `-:` in J? Under what circumstances will we apply `assert` in order to proceed? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`assert` is a name for the defined verb

```
assert=: 0 0 $ 13!:8^:((0 e. ])`(12"_))
```

which looks complicated but actually is just testing for a `0` anywhere in a vector using `(0 e. ])` If there is a zero then `(12"_)` ,which is a way to write a verb that returns `12` no matter what its argument, is sent to `13!:8` which is the foreign conjunction that signals errors. Not surprisingly `12` signals an `assert` error which is what you want having used `assert`. The `0 0 $` in the front assures that after the error interaction begins on the very next line.

The monadic form `-:` (Half) does not usually come into play when used with `assert`. Dyadic `-:` (Match) comes into play as a way to see if two things are a match to each other and it returns a `1` if they are and a `0` otherwise. This means that the standard way of using `assert` and `-:` together are in this form.

```
assert (expected result) -: (computed result)
```

If the computed result matches the expected result there is no `assert` error, if it does not then an `assert` error is raised. Using numerous `assert` tests allows a test driven development environment.

Comment: I see. Kind of like key word 'try' in Python and will raise error in some cases. Thank you for your explanation.